# Overriding const method not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, overriding, constants, parent-child

I'm making a geometry program thing with a base class "Shape" and then a bunch of shapes as derived classes, Point, Rectangle, Triangle, Sphere etc. 
I create a linked list of shapes (currently only point objects) and then I want to go through them and use their print method. But currently the base class' print method is called, not the derived class.

Here is the (relevant part of the) base class.

```
//Shape.h
class Shape
{
public:
    double x, y;
    Shape();
    ~Shape();

    virtual void print() const;
};
```

And then the implementation in the base class

```
//Shape.cpp
#include "Shape.h"
Shape::Shape(){}
void Shape::print() const
{
    cout << "Print base class" << endl;
}
```

Now here are the Point.h and Point.cpp

```
//Point.h
class Point : public Shape
{
private:
    double area;
public:
    Point();
    Point(double x, double y, double area);
    ~Point();

    double getArea() const;

    void print() const;
};
```

The cpp file

```
//Point.cpp
#include "Point.h"
Point::Point()
{
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
    area = 1.0;
}
Point::Point(double xx, double yy, double a) 
{
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    area = a;
}
double Point::getArea() const
{
    return area;
}
void Point::print() const
{
    cout << "Point print area: " << endl;
}
```

When I then call the print method from a Point pointer the base method is called.

In a class called ShapeList I add shape objects to the list like this:

```
void ShapeList::add(const Shape &s)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;

    temp->data = &s;//Set myShape to the memory address of s
    temp->next = head;//Set the next value of the Node
    head = temp;//The head of the current shapelist is now the adress of the new node.
}
```

And then want to print them like this:

```
void ShapeList::print() const
{
    Node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        ptr->data->print();
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

But the base class print method is called. Does anyone know why? I tried adding override keywords in the Point class, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You probably "sliced off" the override on the way to the list. You need to make sure that there is no code that assigns a `Point` to `Shape` by value.

Comment: [OT]: your destructor of `Shape` should be `virtual`. And you may use `std::list<const Shape*>` instead of rewriting your own list.

Comment: @Jarod42 In principle I agree with you, but `std::list<Shape*>` raises other problems. What about `std::list<std::unique:ptr<Shape>>`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: `ShapeList` doesn't seem to own the pointer, that's why I don't suggest smart pointer.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. a single file that compiles and shows the error. As it stands, it's not clear where your error is. It may be that you've simply not linked against the file containing the definition of `Point::print` or that you've sliced a `Point`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer to my own question. The problem was in the "Add" method. In order to make the child call its functions I needed to add a *copy* of the Shape to the list.

This is the code that ended up working

```
void ShapeList::add(const Shape &s)
{
    //Create the node that will be added to the list
    Node* temp;
    temp = new Node(s.clone());

    //Loop to the end of the list.
    Node* ptr;
    ptr = new Node();
    ptr = head;
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        while (ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        //At the end, add another Node to the last Node
        ptr->next = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        head = temp;
    }
}
```

With the new Clone method just being

```
Shape* Shape::clone() const
{
    return new Shape(*this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the base class print method is called. Does anyone know why?

Your print function in Point class is not virtual.

EDIT: As Jarod42 pointed out this is not an issue.

Comment: `void Shape::print() const` is virtual, so `void Point::print() const` is too (even if the `virtual` keyword is not repeated).

Comment: Oops I can't believe I'm not aware of this for years. Thanks.